# Calculating the standard errors of autoregressive terms and sigma in censored regression model

Tags: r, confidence-interval, standard-error

I have fitted a censored regression model in R using `carx` package. 
The data I'm using has 130 observations

```
 head(SAdata)
 # A tibble: 6 x 10
  CC   lcl   Dum    ci   CPI    LI      FDI     FPI       OI Inflows
<dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1  0.617   2.00     0  2.00  4.94  23.3 -0.207   -0.0320 -0.924   -1.16  
2  0.410   2.00     0  2.00  2.92  20.5 -0.246   -0.128   0.0749  -0.299 
3  0.196   2.00     0  2.00  4.26  17.2 -0.177   -0.0763 -0.482   -0.736 
4  0.0518  2.00     0  2.00  5.90  15.5  0.00493 -0.313  -1.59    -1.90  
5 -0.255   2.00     0  2.00  3.29  14.8 -0.0187  -0.200  -1.38    -1.59  
6 -0.392   2.00     0  2.00  4.43  14   -0.00292 -0.0860 -0.00519 -0.0941
> dim(SAdata)
[1] 130  10


library(carx)
SAmodel <- carx(y=SAdata$CC, x=SAdata[,c("CPI","LI","FDI","FPI", "OI")], lcl=1.996866, p=2, CI.compute = FALSE, CI.level = 0.95)

summary(SAmodel)
 Call:
carx.default(y = SAdata$CC, x = SAdata[, c("CPI", "LI", "FDI", "FPI", "OI")], lcl = 1.996866, p = 2, CI.compute = FALSE, CI.level = 0.95)


Coefficients:
  Estimate
CPI     0.0804
LI     -0.0088
FDI    -0.0395
FPI    -0.0166
OI      0.0488
AR1     1.6324
AR2    -0.7097
sigma   0.4286

AIC:
[1] -72.92045
```

But what I got in return is only the estimates without confidence intervals, the confidence intervals in this package are calculated with bootstrapping, which takes a lot of time, when I set the argument `IC.compute = T` with 1000 iterations (from what've read that is the least number of iterations), it took a whole day and it didn't finish. For this reason, I tried to manually calculate the standard errors of every coefficient, but I couldn't find a way to calculate the standard error for the autoregressive terms and sigma.

Here's what I tried

```
#Calculating the residuals of the fitted model
SAres = residuals(SAmodel,type="raw")
# Find the sum of the squared residuals
rss <- sum(SAres^2)
# And use that to find the estimate of sigma^2, commonly called S
S <- sqrt(rss / (length(SAres) - length(SAmodel$coefficients)))
# Make the X matrix; a column of 1s for the intercept and one for each variable
X <- cbind(rep( nrow(SAdata)), SAdata$CPI, SAdata$LI,SAdata$FDI, SAdata$FPI, 
SAdata$OI)
# Multiply matrices using %*%, transpose them with t(),
# and invert them with solve(); and directly apply the formula above with:
std.errors <- S * sqrt(diag(solve(t(X) %*% X)))

std.errors
[1] 0.001232184 0.037669933 0.010483153 0.068843648 0.040779940 0.063888636
```

I don't how to include the autoregressive terms (AR1, AR2) and sigma, because their calculations are based on the response variable. How to get standard errors of these parameters?

I need to calculate the standard errors so later I'll be able to compute the confidence intervals of each coefficient.

Any help is deeply appreciated

Comment: Normally 200 bootstrap repetitions should suffice. You may want to compare the results of the example in `?carx:::carx.default` with 1000 (default) and just 200 reps. set repetitions by option `b=200`. However, the question better should have been asked on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @jay.sf How long it takes for calculating bootstrap confidence intervals with 200 iterations. The model above doesn't supply the SE either, but by plotting the fitted values along with the observed ones, the two lines are almost identical, so that may tell that errors are extremely small. Bootstrapping may not be needed because I'm confident that my parameters will be significant with normal calculations of standard errors and confidence intervals.

Comment: Yes it does, you need the summary, though, `summary(mdl)`.

Comment: If you are referring to `prmtrEstd` values in the outputs, those values are equal to the coefficients, so t statistics will be equal to one

Comment: open `?carx:::carx.default`. Scroll down to the bottom. In last line, set `CI.compute = TRUE`, runs the default 1000 reps around 6 minutes. Do `summary(mdl)`. Then do it again but also set `b=200` for just 200 reps., runs around 1-2 minutes.  Do `summary(mdl)` again and compare results. That's what I actually meant.

Comment: I just did what you've suggested and the results were the same, the 200 and 1000 iterations give the same outcome, anyway I need to form censoring indicators, but I still need some clarification. To form the censoring indicator, observations that need to be censored are those who are believed to be inaccurate and are given the value 1 so they would be censored in the regression. The rest of the observations will be given the value 0 and they will be left uncensored, am I right?

Comment: Sounds reasonable, however please ask this kind of statistical question on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in order to get best answers.